# SSRS display Georgian and Armenian script

Tags: text, reporting-services, character-encoding, character

I am running a test on an SSRS report to ensure that any data the user enters can be displayed correctly. The query contains the following string as nvarchar:

ربيالأردбъл (Бъля)àčދިވެހިބަސްΕλλάñøગુજરાहिं       日本ქაಕನ್ನಡ한국कोंकКमराठीसंस्कृतБосна и Херцеговина)ไทยاُردو中文(简体)фхцчшщ

In the text box where this is displayed in the report, most of this displays properly. However, there are two small portions which do not: Հայ, which is Armenian text; and ქა, which is Georgian. These two display rectangles instead of the characters, as if it cannot display those characters. Does anyone know how I can get it to display these characters properly like the rest of the string? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else needs an answer to this, it turned out not to be anything with the compiler or SSRS, but just the font. Arial, it seems, doesn't support those characters. I switched the font to Arial Unicode MS, which looks the same but has the characters supported, and that fixed characters.